# Web3.js getBlock() is giving me all blocks as pending

Tags: node.js, web3js, ganache

I have a local blockchain running on http://127.0.0.1:7545 using Ganache. There are 8 blocks on the blockchain, none of them is pending.

I've made a script in nodejs that uses web3 to get data from the blocks, but for some reason it isn't working.

This is the script:

```
Web3 = require('Web3')
const web3 = new Web3('http://127.0.0.1:7545')
console.log(web3.eth.getBlockNumber())
var block = web3.eth.getBlock('latest')
console.log(block)
var firstblock = web3.eth.getBlock(0)
console.log(firstblock)
console.log(firstblock.hash)
```

and this is the script execution output

```
>node script.js
 Promise { <pending> }
 Promise { <pending> }
 Promise { <pending> }
 undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getBlock` method always returns a [promise](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#getblock). You should add a `.then()` if you want to access to the block object.
So it should be something like this:

```js
Web3 = require('Web3')
const web3 = new Web3('http://127.0.0.1:7545')

web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(console.log)

var block = web3.eth.getBlock('latest')
block.then(console.log)

var firstblock = web3.eth.getBlock(0)
firstblock.then(console.log)
firstblock.then( block => console.log(block.hash))
```

Comment: @francesco what do you mean? Where to store?

Comment: in a var, i tried like this: "
var blockhash=firstblock.then(block => block.hash)" but it doesn't work. Sorry, first time I deal with Promise objects